# Issue installing R4.0 in AWS Ubuntu focal aarch64

Tags: 20.04, amazon-ec2, arm, r

I am trying to install R4.0 package in the arm64 ubuntu server (focal) on th AWS. I followed the install instruction on this web site, https://rtask.thinkr.fr/installation-of-r-4-0-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-and-tips-for-spatial-packages/ and worked without a hitch when installing R4.0 on the x86_64 ubuntu server. I tried potential solutions posted on the web but none has worked so far. At this point, I'd really appreciate any pointer to address this issue.

The error I get after firing `sudo apt install r-base` are as follows;

```
sudo apt install r-base
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 4.0.3-1.2004.0) but it is not going to be      installed
      Depends: r-recommended (= 4.0.3-1.2004.0) but it is not going to be installed
      Recommends: r-base-html but it is not going to be installed
      Recommends: r-doc-html but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

AWS system info

```
neofetch --stdout
ubuntu@ip-172-31-17-200
-----------------------
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS aarch64
Host: a1.metal 1.0
Kernel: 5.4.0-1029-aws
Packages: 797 (dpkg), 5 (snap)
Shell: zsh 5.8
Terminal: /dev/pts/0
CPU: (16)

cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
ERSION="20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: @N0rbert ,   All the repos including "universe" were already installed.

Comment: @karel,  tried Aptitude but it installed the older 3.6.3-2 version of R.  When checked with apt-cache showpkg r-base-core, it gave me the only one version, 3.6.3-2 but not 4.0.3-1.2004.0.  This suggests the latest 4.0.3-1.2004.0 version may not be available for arm64 ?

Comment: @akh22 Only the r-base-core 3.6.3-2 package for arm64 exists in the default 20.04 repositories. Link: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/armhf/r-base-core/download

Comment: Please add the output of `apt-cache policy r-base r-base-core r-base-dev r-recommended` to the question body.

Comment: R 4.x is not (yet) available for Ubuntu on ARM: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

@Karel,   That's what I thought.  I tried manually compiple R 4.0.3 but am having some issues.

I am not 100% sure but a culprit of the issue may be `r-api-4.0`, as the aptitude output indicates;  `r-cran-boot : Depends: r-api-4.0 which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package`

@NObert,   This is not the answer but the cache-policy output too long for the comment but a following is the entire output of apt cache-policy

> apt-cache policy

```
apt-cache policy r-base r-base-core r-base-dev r-recommended
r-base:
Installed: (none)
Candidate: 4.0.3-1.2004.0
Version table:
4.0.3-1.2004.0 500
500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/                
Packages
4.0.2-1.2004.0 500
    500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/    
Packages
 4.0.1-1.2004.0 500
    500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ 
Packages
 4.0.0-1.2004.0 500
    500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ 
Packages
 3.6.3-2 500
    500 http://us-east-2.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports  
    focal/universe arm64 Packages
 r-base-core:
 Installed: (none)
 Candidate: 3.6.3-2
 Version table:
 3.6.3-2 500
    500 http://us-east-2.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports 
      focal/universe arm64 Packages
 r-base-dev:
 Installed: (none)
 Candidate: 4.0.3-1.2004.0
 Version table:
 4.0.3-1.2004.0 500
    500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ 
 Packages
 4.0.2-1.2004.0 500
    500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ 
 Packages
 4.0.1-1.2004.0 500
    500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ 
 Packages
 4.0.0-1.2004.0 500
    500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ 
 Packages
 3.6.3-2 500
    500 http://us-east-2.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports 
     focal/universe arm64 Packages
 r-recommended:
 Installed: (none)
 Candidate: 4.0.3-1.2004.0
 Version table:
 4.0.3-1.2004.0 500
    500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ 
 Packages
 4.0.2-1.2004.0 500
    500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/   
 Packages
 4.0.1-1.2004.0 500
    500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ 
 Packages
 4.0.0-1.2004.0 500
    500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ 
 Packages
 3.6.3-2 500
    500 http://us-east-2.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports 
 focal/universe arm64 Packages
```